# centre and automorphism groups of finite group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $G$ be a group scheme over a scheme $X$ with centre $Z(G)$, automorphism group $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and outer automorphism group $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ (viewed as group schemes on $X$).

> 1. If $G$ is *finite flat* over $X$, then are $Z(G), \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ also finite flat over $X$?
> 2. If $G$ is *finite étale* over $X$, then are $Z(G), \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ also finite étale over $X$?

Comment: If $G$ is $\mu_p$ over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, then the central fiber of $\text{Aut}(G)$ has length divisible by $p$, because it is non-reduced, yet the generic fiber has length $p-1$.

Comment: Actually, that comment was wrong.  There is an 'etale group scheme over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ of length $p-1$ acting on $G$ faithfully.

Comment: Here is my second attempt.  The $p$-torsion over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ of an elliptic curve with supersingular reduction is a group scheme $M$ whose closed fiber is $\mu_p\times \alpha_p$.  Let $G$ be $M\times_{\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}_p)}M$.  Then the closed fiber is a product $\mu_p^2 \times \alpha_p^2$.  The automorphism group scheme of $\alpha_p^2$ is positive dimensional: it contains a copy of $\textbf{GL}_2$.

Comment: Those functors need not be representable for $G$ not finite fppf (e.g.,${\rm{Aut}}_{\mathbf{G}_a/R}$ isn't for $R$ not a $\mathbf{Q}$-algebra). Assume $G$ is finite fppf. The Aut-scheme exists as affine of finite presentation (coordinate ring for $G$ is vector bundle, etc.), so $Z(G)$ exists as $\ker(G\to{\rm{Aut}}_{G/X})$. *If* $Z(G)$ is flat (can fail!) then $G/Z(G)$ exists and $G/Z(G)\to{\rm{Aut}}_{G/X}$ is finite and monic, so a closed immersion, so ${\rm{Out}}_{G/X}$ exists. That being said, #2 is "yes" by reducing to constant $G$, but ${\rm{Aut}}_{\alpha^n_p/\mathbf{F}_p}={\rm{GL}}_n$.

Comment: Here is an example with non-flat center in case #1. Consider the standard inclusion $j:\alpha_p \hookrightarrow {\rm{GL}}_2$ into the upper-triangular unipotent subgroup $\mathbf{G}_a$. Over $R=\mathbf{F}_p[t]$ we define $i:\alpha_p \rightarrow {\rm{GL}}_{2/R}$ by $x \mapsto j_R(tx)$ and then form the semi-direct product $G :=\alpha_p \ltimes (\alpha_p \times \alpha_p)$ over $R$ using the action through $i$. Then $Z(G)|_{t \ne 0} = \alpha_p \times (\alpha_p \times \{0\})$ but $Z(G)_0 = Z(G)$, so due to such jumping of fiber-rank we see that the finite $Z(G)$ is not flat.

Comment: @JasonStarr: The automorphism scheme of $\mu_n$ is $(\mathbf{Z}/(n))^{\times}$ over any base, by Cartier duality, and the Aut-scheme of $\alpha_p^n$ (over any $\mathbf{F}_p$-scheme) is ${\rm{GL}}_n$ on the nose because the endomorphism scheme is ${\rm{Mat}}_n$ (which in turn is reduced to the case $n=1$ that is seen by bare hands).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It seems that the answer to #1 is always no. But the answer to #2 is always yes? One proves this by reducing to the case of the constant scheme and applying descent? Could you please provide this step in an answer @nfdc23?

Comment: Typo: in my 2nd comment above, "$Z(G)_0 = Z(G)$" should have been "$Z(G)_0=G_0$" (as I suppose was clear). As for the request to type up the argument in the finite etale case as an answer...I'll let someone else do that if it is important to do so. Personally I don't think it is (and the point stuff is irrelevant to me), especially since the counterexamples to #1 (such as given in Friedrich Knop's answer below) seem rather more interesting than the affirmative proof of #2 (which is a standard exercise with descent that those who know descent can work out for themself).

Comment: @nfdc23: I was just trying to follow standard mathoverflow practice by making sure the answer is not hidden in the comments to help others who may stumble upon this question. I was just offering to give you the credit if you wanted it, but if not I'm happy to write the answer up.

Comment: @DanielLoughran: That's fine; it wasn't apparent how much detail you were seeking to be written in an official answer concerning #2.  Thanks for following through on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers to 1. are all no since a finite flat group scheme can have fibers of very different isomorphism type.

Here is an example of a finite flat group scheme where $Z(G)$ is not finite flat: Let $k$ be algebraically closed of odd characteristic $p$ and $X=\mathbf A^1$. Let $G$ be the closed subscheme of $GL_{3,X}$ given by matrices of the form
$$
A=\pmatrix{a&b&x\\sb&a&y\\0&0&1}
$$
subject to the relations $\det A=a^2-sb^2=1$ and $a^p-1=b^p=x^p=y^p=0$.
Here $s$ is the parameter on $X$. For $s\ne0$, the fiber of $G$ is the semidirect product $\mu_p\ltimes\alpha_p^2$ with $\mu_p$ acting by non-trivial characters. In particular, the center is trivial. For $s=0$ the group scheme is unipotent and its center is nontrivial.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to 2. is *yes*.

A sketch of a proof is as follows: $G$, being finite étale, is étale locally on $X$ isomorphic to a constant finite group scheme. Therefore, by a standard descent argument, it suffices to prove the result for constant finite group schemes. However here $Z(G), \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ are all clearly finite étale, as required.